# File 'Makefile' has modification time 86 s in the future

Tags: linux, ros, ubuntu-20.04, catkin

I am having issues making a catkin workspace in ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 20.04. Whenever I try to build I get these errors:

```
make: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 86 s in the future
make[1]: Warning: File 'CMakeFiles/Makefile2' has modification time 86 s in the future
make[1]: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
```

I checked that my date is correct by running the date command (I did it right after I saw the time change on my home and it was right to the second). I also tried the following commands: `find build/. -exec touch {} \;`
`touch build/Makefile`
`touch build/CMakeFiles/Makefile2`
`find ~/new_ws/build/CMakeFiles/Makefile2 -type f -exec touch {} +`
`find ~/new_ws/build/Makefile -type f -exec touch {} +`
And at best, the amount of seconds it was off by decreased a little. The project I am working on was passed down to me from another group and they wrote custom ROS messages. And it appears that this is interfering with it because even when I pull their original git repo, this is the only issue I am having (despite me seeing it work on other devices). Any ideas on how to get my catkin workspace to be made correctly?

Comment: _I checked that my date is correct_ - Did you also check that `Makefile`'s date is correct?

Comment: Just deleted everything and remade it. I checked the properties and it said it was modified at 11:06am when it was 11:04am.

Comment: Honestly I got the error to go away by just spamming `catkin_make clean` but would not recommend doing that. Now it's saying `catkin: command not found` when I try to build, so yikes.

Comment: I'd try to investigate wherefrom the file gets its wrong date. I've seen such only on network drives on unsynchronized servers.

Comment: Yeh, I'm using computers in my university's robotics lab. Wouldn't surprise me if that is causing those issues. But I don't have root or admin access so I don't think there's much I can do about it unfortunately.